# Select records where column value is unique

Tags: sql

I have a table of posts in a forum (`mybb_posts`, with the `username` of the poster).

I want all the posts posted by people who only posted once, in other words, all the rows where `username` is a single occurrence in the `username` column.

So far I am using this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mybb_posts
WHERE username IN
    (SELECT username
     FROM
       (SELECT username,
               count(*) COUNT
        FROM `mybb_posts`
        GROUP BY username) tbl1
     WHERE COUNT=1)
```

But the three nested SELECTs look ugly.

Is there a more elegant/efficient/simple way? All the answers I have seen on SO and elsewhere focus on getting the unique ids.

This is for a MySQL database, if you want to suggest non-standard solutions (but standard ones are preferred).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all the rows where username is a single occurrence in the username column.

This suggests window functions:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.username) as cnt
      FROM mybb_posts p
     ) p
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

As a note:  You don't need two nested subqueries for your version.  You can use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM mybb_posts p
WHERE p.username IN (SELECT p2.username
                     FROM mybb_posts p2
                     GROUP BY p2.username
                     HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                    );
```

Comment: No PARTITION in my version of MySQL. Tried to use HAVING but as I used it it didn't reduce the number of SELECT. Thx for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

The most portable solution that I can think of is `not exists` and a correlated subquery. This works in most databases, including those that do not support window functions (such as MySQL 5.x versions, or MS Access). This should also be a rather efficient option.

For this, you need a primary key in your table. Assuming that it is called `post_id`, that would be:

```
select p.*
from mybb_posts p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mybb_posts p1
    where p1.username = p.username and p1.post_id <> p.post_id
)
```

For performance, you need an index on `(username, post_id)`.

Comment: Without such an index, it took several minutes (17K posts, 2K users). Nice trick, though, up to now my WNE usage was limited to avoiding duplicates in database insertions.